# What does "normal userland code" mean in the SQLAlchemy documentation?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I was reading ["Changing Attribute Behavior – Simple Validators"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_attributes.html) and it says

> Validators, like all attribute extensions, are only called by normal
>   userland code; they are not issued when the ORM is populating the
>   object

My questions are:

1. What does "normal userland code" mean? (Please translate it to easy English.)
2. What does it mean that validators are "issued"? I know that validators are Python decorators. Do we say "issued" when a decorator is interpreted by the Python interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

The way SQLAlchemy populates ORM objects as a result of a query is [more akin to how for example `pickle` unmarshals objects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/constructors.html). It does not for example call the `__init__()` method, or set attributes through the usual [instrumented attribute](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute) descriptors. In this sense "normal userland code" could mean just that, code that sets attributes the usual way:

```
In [3]: class Foo(Base):
   ...:     __tablename__ = 'foo'
   ...:     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   ...:     bar = Column(Unicode)
   ...:     
   ...:     @validates('bar')
   ...:     def validate_bar(self, key, value):
   ...:         assert value.endswith('bar')
   ...:         return value
   ...:     

In [4]: Foo(bar='testbarnot')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
  ...
AssertionError: 

In [5]: foo = Foo(bar='testbar')

In [6]: foo.bar = 'testxyzzy'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
  ...
AssertionError: 

In [7]: foo.bar = 'test2bar'
```

On the other hand if you've managed to insert invalid values to a table, querying will not trigger validation:

```
In [10]: session.execute(Foo.__table__.insert().values(bar='thisshouldfail'))
Out[10]: <sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy at 0x7f19bc826048>

In [11]: session.commit()

In [12]: fs = session.query(Foo).all()

In [13]: fs[0].bar
Out[13]: 'thisshouldfail'
```

Neither does sidestepping the ORM instrumentation, or in other words the event system:

```
In [14]: failer = Foo()

In [15]: failer.__dict__['bar'] = 'thisshouldalsofail'

In [16]: session.add(failer)

In [17]: session.commit()
```

I guess the word "issued" is chosen just because of the validation context and the fact that they're implemented using the [SQLAlchemy event system](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extending.html). You could also read "they are [not] called", "triggered", or "applied". The `validates` decorator is just a helper that hides the details of registering [attribute events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.AttributeEvents).